# iPhone 5 says "disabled, connect to iTunes" but iTunes says it "can't connect because of an unexpected error"

Tags: iphone, itunes

I rebooted it but it still says "iPhone is disabled, connect to iTunes" even though I don't have a password on it anymore because I rebooted it. When I try to connect it to iTunes it says "Can't connect to iPhone because of an unexpected error.

Comment: _i don't have a password on it anymore because i rebooted it._ Do you mean you have reset it?

Comment: I already reset it but it didn't do anything. After i rebooted it it just said "iPhone is disabled connect to iTunes" and the background was just a black screen.

Comment: Is iTunes able to detect your iPhone? Try with a different cable. Typically you should be able to restore from a backup or setup the iPhone as a new device.

Comment: Make sure iTunes is up to date. I get strange issues all the time if I try to sync my phone without updating it first.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on iTunes first. You need a working version of iTunes and can test with another phone if you aren’t sure your iTunes is ready to restore any phone and not just the one that’s disabled.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263

The disabled unlock will be your next hurdle, but get iTunes working unless you want to take the phone to another computer for erasing and determining the unlock status.

- [Unlocking a disabled iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294611/unlocking-a-disabled-iphone)